# Trying to understand binary search

Tags: ruby, binary-search

I'm trying to understand this code my pairing partner wrote. I dont understand why she used the until loop stating to loop until (finish - start) == 1. What exactly is she looping until?

```
def binary_search(object, array)
  array.sort!
  start = -1
  finish = array.length

  until (finish - start) == 1 do
    median =  start + ((finish - start) / 2)
    # p start
    # p finish
    return median if object == array[median]
  if object > array[median]
    start = median
  elsif object < array[median]
    finish = median
  end
 end
 -1
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finish - start` is the length of the window left to search (+ 1, for easier arithmetic); it starts of as the entire array and gets halved on every iteration, by setting either the start or the finish to the median.

When it reaches 1, there is nothing left to search, and the input object was not found.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how kids play the "guess a number between 1 and 100" game. "Is it bigger than 50?" "No." You now know it's a number between 1 and 50. "Is it bigger than 25?" "Yes." You now know it's between 26 and 50. And so on...

It's the same with binary search.  You check to see if the target is above or below the midrange.  Whichever way the answer turns out, you've eliminated half of the possibilities and can focus on the remaining subset.  Every time you repeat the process, you cut the range that's still under consideration in half.  When the range gets down to size one, you've either found the target value or established it wasn't in the set.